# How to localize bitmap font?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I usually have 4 files per font. For instance

```
menu-ipadhd.fnt
menu-ipadhd.png
menu.fnt
menu.png
```

Question is, should I localize all 4 files or `.fnt` localization is enough? Can Cocos2D find png file from corresponding `.lproj`? What is the proper way to localize bitmap fonts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether cocos2d finds files according to language is easy to test, put two different files one in en.lproj and the other in some other language folder, then change the device's or simulators language and see whether it picks the correct one for each language.

If you are meaning to [localize the text](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/BPInternational.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000171i) (strings displayed with a bitmap font) you really just have to localize the strings and make sure that for all supported languages all language-specific characters (äéøß and such) are included in the bitmap font's image. At least all of those actually used by your localized strings.

If you are localizing to a completely different character set, for example from english to cyrillic, asian or arabic languages, you need to provide different bitmap fonts altogether, ie both fnt and png files and load them according to the language. This is next to localizing the text itself.

The reason is that these non-latin character sets contain hundreds if not thousands of different characters, so including them in a single bitmap font is not desirable and may not even be possible to fit them all in 4096x4096 (or less) texture space.

Some cocos2d version's bitmap font class limits the number of characters in a bitmap font to 2048 - this may apply only to v1.x I haven't checked if that limitation still exists in 2.x in general, I just can't locate it in 2.1 anymore. For character sets that exceed this number of characters you will have to increase that number in the header of CCBMFontLabel - if available.

Be careful though with large bitmap fonts as the storage per letter can add up quite significantly, an entire font can use several megabytes - not counting the texture itself!

Comment: I mean character set included in `fnt/png` pair. So far I've localized both - `fnt` and `png` files and it works fine. I was thinking that there is no need to localize png files and I can simply copy it to project, since there is a reference to it from fnt file.

Comment: good, I initially misunderstood what you meant hence the largely offtopic answer ;)

Comment: Your answers are always helpful, even off-topic ones :)